# Add Model Binding attributes of ASP.NET Core to class in class library project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-binding

I have a model in a class library project. I want to exclude a public get set the property from model binding of ASP.NET Core.

From MS docs, I see the instruction to use attributes in `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding` for handling model binding behavior. But I then found that I cannot add references to use these attributes. Do we have any solution for this issue?

Comment: have you installed required packages succesfully in your class library project?

Comment: I've find the answer, tks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I find solution in here.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/target-aspnetcore

We need to add framework reference in `.csproj` file.

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
  </ItemGroup>
```